# SQL: How to select Row that has youngest Date OR timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with three columns, that ist result of a Select with an inner join:

```
SELECT createTimestamp, paymentDate, buyDate
FROM ARC_PAYMENTS 
INNER JOIN PERSON_IN_PAYMENT ON ARC_PAYMENTS.PERSON_ID=PERSON_IN_PAYAMENT.ID
WHERE PERSON_IN_PAYMENT.COMPANY_ID='1234567';
```

Now, I need to get the latest/youngest/highest value of the three columns of all rows. So the result should be just one Date.
That might be problematic because the createTimestamp column is a timestamp, the other two columns are date.

Is there any way to do that (performance is very important) in a oracle database? To use the result of my first SELECT in another select?

Thank you

Comment: you need to edit your question, show **complete** table DDL, and sample data, expected output.

Comment: You want `trunc(greatest(t1, d1, d2))` ?

Comment: Do you mean one date per row or one date across all rows/columns? GREATEST() will give you the max value across columns and MAX will give you the max value between rows - so one or the other (or a combination of the two) should give you what you want

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `GREATEST` function.

```
SELECT GREATEST(CAST(createTimestamp AS DATE), paymentDate, buyDate) 
FROM ARC_PAYMENTS 
INNER JOIN PERSON_IN_PAYMENT ON ARC_PAYMENTS.PERSON_ID=PERSON_IN_PAYAMENT.ID
WHERE PERSON_IN_PAYMENT.COMPANY_ID='1234567';
```

Comment: I get "null" for ever line, propably because for every row one of the three attributes is null and GREATEST takes the null value as every date. Is there a possibilty to ignore null-Attributes or to handle them als smaller than a real date?

Comment: ```GREATEST``` doesn't have any options, but you could use ```COALESCE``` on the arguments as described in the 1st answer on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186283/handling-null-in-greatest-function-in-oracle).